# Running Tomcat https and http for different apps

Tags: https, tomcat, http

I have 2 apps on Tomcat, I want https for app1 and http for app2. I've dug around and found info on dual http and https for the same app, but how to I isolate 2 apps for the 2 modes?

Answer (score 1):

Put a "reverse proxy" (or a superset of it, a web load balancer) between your Tomcat and the users' browsers. I'd recommend HAproxy or nginx (proxy_pass directive) to power it. These let you play with causing `/some/url/path` to return 404 on https and `/another` to return 404 on pure http.

If you're on a cloud use the native load balancer of that cloud (GCP, AWS).

I would recommend to simplify Tomcat configuration as much as possible and not enable https on Tomcat.